# ACF plugin relationship field, if no value in nav tab,want to hide the tab

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using bootstrap nav tab and acf custom field in my wp theme. I want to hide a nav tab if there is no value in relation. How to do that? Below is my code--
i want to hide the compatible with tab, if relation dont return any value

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#compatibility" aria-controls="compatibility" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Compatibility </a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#datasheet" aria-controls="datasheet" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Datasheet</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#order" aria-controls="order" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Order</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="compatibility">
                <?php
                  $posts = get_field('compatible_with');
                  if( $posts ): ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>" rel="</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="datasheet"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="order"></div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

i want to use this function

```
if( count( get_field('compatible_with') ) > 0 ) :
```

Comment: What type of field is your ACF? I'm assuming a repeater.

Comment: @disinfor relation type field

Comment: If there is no relationship, then nothing will be output from the loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: @disinfor yeah! And when nothing will generate, there won't be this tab

Comment: Ah, so you basically want the tabs above (overview, compatility, etc.) to not display if there is no tab content.

Comment: @disinfor yeah u r so right!

Answer (score 0):

Any ways just using these two lines of code, I sorted out the problem

```
<?php if( get_field('compatible_with') ): ?>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#compatibility" aria-controls="compatibility" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Compatibility </a></li>    
<?php endif; ?>
```